# Spark-Submit ClassNotFoundException even with package name

Tags: apache-spark

I have my main scala class in package `sparks.seql.project` and I am submitting my Spark job in client mode with command:

```
spark-submit --class sparks.seql.project.EcommDataReader --master yarn --deploy-mode client D:\Spark-Workspace\Big-Data-Project\untitled\out\artifacts\Spark_Scala_jar\Spark-Scala.jar
```

Still I am getting:

```
2020-05-04 22:32:37,919 WARN deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2: Failed to load sparks.seql.project.EcommDataReader.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sparks.seql.project.EcommDataReader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:810)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2020-05-04 22:32:38,004 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
2020-05-04 22:32:38,010 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-83beb237-5bf6-4e84-881a-60b63135f7e3
```

My code is like this:

```
package sparks.seql.project

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object EcommDataReader {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SapientQ1")
    .master("yarn")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    //    .config("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://localhost:9083")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file://f:/sparkWarehouse/")
    .config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true")
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "non-strict")
    .config("spark.yarn.am.memory","512m")
    .config("spark.yarn.am.cores","1")

    .config("spark.eventLog.dir","D:/sparkeventlog/")
    .getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
...
...
```

Though seems to be a small problem but nothing worked!

**UPDATE:**

build.sbt

```
name := "Spark-Scala"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

val sparkVersion = "2.4.3"

val kafkaVersion = "0.11.0.0"

dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.7"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.7"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.8.7"

//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.7.7"
//
//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % "2.1.0" % Test
//
//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-exec" % "2.1.0"
//
//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-metastore" % "2.1.0"
//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-jdbc" % "0.13.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % sparkVersion

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % sparkVersion

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % sparkVersion

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % kafkaVersion

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % sparkVersion

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "connect-json" % "2.4.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-yarn" % "2.4.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.4.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.4.3"

//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.7.4"
```

I am building jar as **`Build -> Build Artifacts.. -> build`** in intellij

Comment: Are you able to run the JAR file using `java -jar <location>\Spark-Scala.jar`? If you see the `ClassNotFoundException` error again that means this `EcommDataReader` never got included in the JAR.. Also can you post your `build.sbt`?

Comment: Yes. I decompiled the jar and checked the main class is present at correct package

Comment: Are you able to run the jar using the Java command?

Comment: No. That also giving the same error. Admit that something wrong with Jar. But I am using intellij to build the jar. ANy suggestions where I could have gone wrong

Comment: How does your `build.sbt` look like? Also, how are you creating the JAR?

Comment: I have updated my question. Build.sbt included

Comment: You're building jar the wrong way when you have spark dependencies. You must sbt assembly plugin to create a jar in that case. Also you might mark the Spark dependencies as provided so that jar build doesn't take time.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. Could you please tell me how to do that in Intellij? Thank you so much

Comment: For the `"org.apache.spark"` based `libraryDependencies`, add a `% "provided"` in the end. For sbt assembly plugin: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Comment: Still did not work

Comment: Is it still the same error? Also after you use the SBT Assembly to build the JAR, are you taking the JAR created inside `target/scala-2.11/` folder? That JAR will have `assembly` somewhere in the name...

Comment: I actually have the same error, also I'm sure the main class exists in the jar, but just got the error, have you found the solution? @DrthSprk_